# Segmentation fault (core dumped) (very simple program)

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault

I'm having this problem writing a very basic program to learn arrays in C. The message appears when putting more than 2 in the array size.
SO: Linux, Clear Linux OS 64 bits

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int array[0], k=0, init;
    
    printf ("Insert amount of values\n");
    scanf ("%i", &init);

    for (k=1; k<=init; k++) {
        printf ("Insert values:");
        scanf ("%i", &array[k]);
    }
    for (k=1; k<=init; k++) {
        printf("%i,", array[k]);
    }

     return 0;
}
```

```
Insert amount of values
3
Insert values:4
Insert values:2
Insert values:3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Tried changing the data type of the array and the `"%i"` to `"%d"`

Comment: Hint: How many values can you store in a **zero length** array?

Comment: you've declared `array` to have length `0`, it doesn't resize automatically

Comment: Arrays in C are not dynamic.

Comment: Also remember that array indexes are *zero* based. So an array of `init` elements will have indexes from `0` to `init - 1` (inclusive).

Comment: You may want to steer away from `%i` as it can have unintended consequences. `%d` is the convention here.

Comment: @tadman and CoffeeTableEspresso I initialized it with 0, is it wrong?

Comment: @Hernan yes. When you make an array in C, the size is fixed. So if you make a zero length array, you cannot ever store more than 0 elements in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing an array of size 1 with `int array[0]`.

You have two options :

1. You declare the array with the biggest expected size for exemple `int array[10]`, but you will just report your problem and get segfault at the 11th value entered.
2. You dynamically manage the size of your arrays with `malloc` function.

Comment: Note: `sizeof(array) == 0`, not `1`.